# How to download file whith camel sftp

Tags: spring, apache-camel

Here is what I must to do : an external server generate periodically 3 files : "FI.date.nnnnn", "FS.date.nnnnn" and GO.date.nnnnn". The 3 files are associated with the same date and nnnnn (=sequence number). Every "triplet" are unique name. I must download the files when the GO file exists. This GO file is empty.

I use camel with this route :

```
from("sftp://user@url:port/OUTTEST-S?binary=true&connectTimeout=3000&delete=true&disconnect=true&include=GO.*&knownHostsFile=.ssh/known_hosts&privateKeyFile=../id_rsa.ppk&stepwise=false&strictHostKeyChecking=no&timeout=3000).bean(afterReceiveGo).to("...")
```

I use "include=GO.*" to wait the GO file.

In my AfterReceiveGo, I use a ConsumerTemplate like this :

```
consumerTemplate.receiveBody(sftp://user@url:port/OUTTEST-S?binary=true&connectTimeout=3000&delete=true&disconnect=true&fileName=FO.20160810.00089&knownHostsFile=.ssh/known_hosts&privateKeyFile=../id_rsa.ppk&stepwise=false&strictHostKeyChecking=no&timeout=3000&useList=false, File.class)
```

As I know the name of file to download, I use "fileName=" and useList=false".

But in the log :

```
Will try again at next poll. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException - Cannot list directory: OUTTEST-S]: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot list directory: OUTTEST-S
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.listFiles(SftpOperations.java:617)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer.doPollDirectory(SftpConsumer.java:117)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer.pollDirectory(SftpConsumer.java:79)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:131)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:175)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:102)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: 4: 
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2208)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2215)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(ChannelSftp.java:1565)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(ChannelSftp.java:1526)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.listFiles(SftpOperations.java:608)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: inputstream is closed
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.fill(ChannelSftp.java:2884)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.header(ChannelSftp.java:2908)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2189)
    ... 16 more
```

I use Camel 2.17.2 and all is java configuration, no xml files.

What is wrong ? Is there another (and best) method to do this ?

Second problem : I would like to use cron expression whith the from("sftp...") to execute every one hour, ie. I can't use "?scheduler=spring&sheduler.cron=..." (nor quartz2) because I have error in deploy (constructor not found). Thus I use :

```
cronScheduledRoutePolicy.startTime("cron expression");
from("sftp...").routePolicy(cronScheduledRoutePolicy).bean("...").to("...");
```

But I see a connect every second in the log file. What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Camel's sftp component has options to define its own poling interval. no need for configuring/adding scheduler. Here are the 2 options referred from http://camel.apache.org/file2.html
initialDelay : Milliseconds before polling the file/directory starts.
delay : Milliseconds before the next poll of the file/directory.